# What terminal to use on AC for C wire / nest dual transformer install

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest, transformer

So i purchased a nest gen 3 and proceeded to install it. This is on a dual transformer system, separate boiler and AC system. The good news was i had a unused G wire on the Heat side that I was going to use to supply constant voltage. I wire everything up turn on the Nest and get E79 error. I checked between C/Rh at the thermostat and around 26 volts. I call up Nest and they tell me that when you have the heat and ac connected to thermostat on a dual transformer system, the nest wants to see power from the AC side. The problem is the AC thermostat wire coming for the air handler only has 3 wires, G/R/Y - in my case the Y is white wire.

Nest tells me i can jump/group the Rc to C on the AC transformer, thats what i understood, or run and new wire and connect to the C wire on the AC transformer.

I have added pictures of my system, the wire will the R/G/Y is going to the thermostat, can I just take the R wire and jump it to the C, basically wire nut a small piece of wire from the R bundle to the Common? If so which one is the common, the blue???

If i run new wire that has an extra wire for the common, where on the transformer/air handler to i connect to. The brown wires look like they go to the compressor. I would basically connect everything as it currently is but where would of tap/connect the new C wire to? Directly to the Transformer where the blue wire is? or could i wire nut the new C wire to the blue/white bundle that is currently wire nutted? Again Im assuming that the blue is the Common.

I guess i can always run a voltmeter from the Rc to the blue to see if i get constant 24 volts.

If someone can point me in the right direction i would really a appreciate it.

[image][image]

[image]

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is your common** [image]
You connect here and bring it up to the stat with the spare wire from the boiler.

Nest is also capable of power stealing in many cases. Here's a link to check before running a new wire.

https://nest.com/ca/support/article/When-Nest-needs-a-common-C-wire#wire-you-checker

Comment: 1st off thanks Joe for your reply, really appreciate it. So I can just use the extra wire on the new thermostat wire that I will be running for the AC to the stat? and connect everything else like it is now correct? This AC is in the attic the boiler is in the basement, 2 separate wires. I would then disconnect the C wire from the boiler and use the spare from the AC? Also what is that extra wire twisted with the blue, is that going to the compressor? i dont want to mess anything up. I really appreciate you taking the time. Paul

Comment: Yes if you do run a new cable for the a/c, reconnect as is and add the common to the blue wire. The white wire tied in is for the contactor in the condensor(compressor) I added a link to the answer. I didn't read it, I just sent it to a customer last night and it helped him get his nest working without a common wire.

Comment: Joe thank you very much, going to run wires this weekend, I will look at the link also.  Btw i know if i take out the c wire from boiler the nest will work, it will pluse of the rh and rc but i want to do it right. Nest wants power from ac side. Paul